# Unable to create list of string SwiftUI from json response

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

I have a list of remarks which I receive from an API call. I have created a loop to create TEXT from the remarks but the texts do not appear in the application. Please check the code.

I have also checked the debugger and it shows a the string present there but it doesn't create the text.

```
            VStack{
                Text("Remarks")
                    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                    .font(.title2)
                if(currentFrResponse.remarks != nil){
                    Text("fine")
                    List(currentFrResponse.remarks!, id:\.self){ currentRemark in
                        Text("Test")
                        Text(currentRemark)
                            .bold()
                            .padding()
                        
                    }
                }
            }
```

[debugger result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2xGI.png)

Let me know if you need any more details

Comment: Off topic but why do you have a VStack around a single Text component? I also don’t think there is enough information here to give an answer to your question

Comment: @joakimDanielson I have added it since I have one more field which I have removed. Can you tell me what else do you need... I will add it here.

Comment: I don’t know what else is needed since I have no idea what might be wrong. If the code is executed as you have seen in the debugger but nothing is shown then maybe the problem is something completely different, like the list gets hidden behind something else. You should perhaps look at what else is done in the view and maybe you can comment out other parts of the code to see if you can make your view visible that way

Comment: I have checked all that and everything works perfectly fine. Even the Text("Remarks") is being added, just not the list.

Comment: Just a hunch since we cannot see your call, but do you dispatch this to the main thread?

Comment: @Patru the currentFrResponse.remarks is a list of strings. Remarks. I wish for it to iterate through the remarks list and add all the strings in the list to the Text box.

Comment: You show the cration of a VStack which looks ok, but where do you put it and why should it show up in a View? Could you try to put this into a runnable Playground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this code in my project and it's working fine, as per my knowledge this issue is something else related to other component or view that you are using in the same controller, But if you want you can try creating individual view for this list and then use it.

```
  var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Remarks")
                .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                .font(.title2)

                List(landmarks, id:\.self){ currentRemark in
                    VStack{
                        Text(currentRemark.name)
                            .bold()
                            .padding()
                    }.padding()
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried by adding a new text beneath the if condition and it works. Its only the list it doesn't print. check the code, I edited it:

Comment: it does print the "fine" but nothing in the list.

Comment: Have you tried creating separate view controller which contain this list only, no other views or component

Comment: thanks I will try this. I am currently not working in this project that is why there was a delay in reply.

Comment: I don't know what is the issue here. If I only change the 'List' to "ForEach" in the above code, it simply works but the list doesn't work. Any suggestions